# Autofill Weekdays in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, formulas

I know you can find the number of days between workdays and other return values, but i am having trouble finding a way to use the Workday or Weekday formula and have it return the next date that is a workday. I would also like to use the Autofill feature to be able to fill it down Column A with the start date Hard Coded in cell A1. (excluding weekends (Saturday, Sunday)) Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 6):

I hope this answer is helpful to others who visit here to find answer.

Here's answer for you: [Autofill weekdays only ...](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/OMuzBd1glQA).

You can autofill weekdays excluding weekend(saturday, sunday) like below

> A2: `first date`
>
> A3: `=A2+IF(WEEKDAY(A2)>5,3,1)`
>
> and fill A3 down.

Note: not **=6** just **>5**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=A1+index({1;1;1;1;1;3;2};weekday(A1))
```

It adds 1 for Sunday-Thursday, 3 for Friday, and 2 for Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

C4 is the start date

D4 is the end date

to compute days, removing weekends:

=if(weekDay(C4)>weekDay(D4),D4-C4-2*int((D4-C4)/7)-1,D4-C4-2*int((D4-C4)/7)+1)

[can't post images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOSGH.jpg)